# Eclipse method signature working with Either

Tags: scala

If you enter the code below in Eclipse and hover `f2` to display the method signature, it is wrong. This happens only when the method returns a Future Either.

Given this code:

```
object HelloScala extends App{
     
      def f1 = Future { 1 }
      
      def f2 = {
        val future = f1
        future.map { 
           case i: Int => Right(1)
           case _ => Left(0)
         }
      }
      
      Thread.sleep(10000)
}
```

Instead of `Future[Either[Int,Int]]`, I see this:

[image]

Any ideas if this is fixable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type Eclipse shows (which is the type inferred by the Scala compiler) is not *wrong*, it's the most accurate type the compiler could find. Why?

All the compiler knows is that this `Future` will either hold a `Left[Int]` or a `Right[Int]`; Both of these types extend these 3 traits:

- `Either[Int, Int]` as expected
- `Product` because both `Left` and `Right` are case classes, and all case classes extend `Product`; and
- `Serializable` for the same reason (all case classes are `Serializable`)

So the inferred type is the combination of all three.

You can easily fix it by explicitly specifying the *desired* type yourself when calling `map`:

```
def f2 = {
  val future = f1
  future.map[Either[Int, Int]] {
    case i: Int => Right(1)
    case _ => Left(0)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, good answer. If I specify explicitly `Either[Int,Int]` will that also help the compiler/run-time to work faster?

Comment: Runtime - no; Compiler - not to any identifyable extent.. It's true that type inference is not a trivial task for the compiler but it's still not a reasonable consideration (for most projects) when deciding whether to explicitly specify the type. Specify the type in cases where the inferred type is less useful / readable (like this case, probably) or per any chosen "styleguide" (e.g. for readability, most style guides recommend explicit types for public methods and values).